# Can someone explain to me how this loop works within function only?

Tags: c++, linked-list, intersection

Studying some linked lists and not sure how this loop works with the assignment.

The code is intended to find the intersection of two linked lists.

```
ListNode *getIntersectionNode(ListNode *headA, ListNode *headB) {
    ListNode *cur1 = headA, *cur2 = headB;
    while(cur1 != cur2){
        cur1 = cur1 ? cur1->next : headB;
        cur2 = cur2 ? cur2->next : headA;
    }
    return cur1;
}
```

I'm not sure how the `cur1 = cur1` is evaluated with assignments rather than a Boolean condition. I understand how the iteration works but unsure of why I can't just do:

```
while(cur1 != cur2){
    cur1 = cur1->next;
    cur2 = cur2->next;
}
return cur1;
```

With this I'm pretty sure I will end up with a runtime error though.

Comment: "Can someone explain to me how this if else loop works?" - there isn't any `if..else` in your code

Comment: `cur1 = cur1` isn't what it says.  It says `cur1 = ( cur1 ? cur1->next : headB );` ... in other words, it checks to see if `cur1` is null before dereferencing it.  In your second `while` loop, if `cur1` or `cur2` is null you will crash.

Comment: ah this is actually really helpful because unless i used this, I had problems getting my programs to compile thanks! @par

Comment: The ? : is a conditional (ternary) operator. So if cur1->next has value then cur1 = cur1->next else it = headA, headB respectively.

Comment: This might help a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415957/how-to-correctly-use-the-ternary-operator

Comment: @artm 

a<5?a=2:b=5 can mean: 

if (a<5) a = 2;
else b = 5;

Answer (score 4):

```
cur1 = cur1?cur1->next:headB;
```

Is a ternary operator. It is checking if `cur1` is null before trying to "move on to the next node"
It is equivalent to:

```
if (cur1 != null){cur1 = cur1->next;}
else {cur1 = headB;}
```

The issue with the version you proposed is that if `cur1` happens to be null, you will get a segmentation fault.